# how to extract HREF from URL using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am not a developer, but trying my hand to get knowladge,  using jquery I am get div HTML, here is my code and result

```
var urls =  document.getElementsByClassName("TFQHme")[0]['previousElementSibling']
console.log(urls);
```

Using this I am getting following result

```
   <div jstcache="986">
      <div aria-label="Zalak Family Salon Hair And Beauty" class="Nv2PK THOPZb CpccDe" 
      <a jsaction="pane.wfvdle146;jstcache="864" href="https://www.google.co.in/maps/place/Zalak+Family+Salon+Hair+And+Beauty/></a>
      <div jstcache="865" class="rWbY0d"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But actually I want a URL link which is here in href, to get this link how to use jquery

Comment: Vanilla.js `document.querySelector('.TFQHme').previousElementSibling.querySelectorAll('a').forEach((el)=>{
  console.log(el.href)
})`

Do not use jquery in 2023!

Answer (score 0):

no it's not jquery you can do (and you are trying to do) without jquery:

> this should work if all you provided is correct

```js
const url = document.getElementsByClassName("TFQHme")[0]['previousElementSibling'].querySelector("a").getAttribute("href")
```